# Customize layout of AmplifySignOut

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I'm currently working on a react app that integrates AWS Amplify. A great tool so far but I find it hard to customize components. Especially I would like to style the AmplifySignOut-component.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/react#usage-1) (see last paragraph on page) passing a theme to the withAuthenticator-component does not work like this anymore.
I can't figure out how to pass a theme to the AmplifySignOut-component that overwrites the default layout for the button that is created. So far, I think that [this](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/e85640a4e18fa1d55411038fee58919ad73121fa/packages/amplify-ui/src/Button.css) is the default layout but I'm not 100% sure.

It would be great, if someone could point me in the right direction here :)

Im using the component like this (not working):

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import './Navbar.css'
import { AmplifySignOut } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';


function Navbar(props) {
  const MyTheme = {
    NavButton: { 'fontWeight': '10' },
  }

  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/pdservice">Drucker & Netzwerk</NavLink>
      <AmplifySignOut theme={MyTheme}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, i just ended up writing a completely custom button which calls the amplify function. you can style this one then completely as you want. maybe this code helps?

```js
import React from 'react'
import {Auth} from "aws-amplify";


function CustomSignoutButton() {
  const signOut = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      Auth.signOut();
      window.location.reload() <!-- it also works without, but just to really kick the user out.-->
    }
  return (
    <button onClick={signOut}>
      Sign out
    </button>
  )
}

export default CustomSignoutButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create new component (in my case it is "src\components\SignOut.js")

```
import React from 'react'
import {Auth} from "aws-amplify";

function SignOutButton() {
    const signOut = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        Auth.signOut().then(()=>{
            window.location.reload(false); 
        });
    }
    return (
        <button onClick={signOut}>
            Sign out
        </button>
    )
}

export default SignOutButton;
```

Import it in your app (remember to replace path with correct one if it differs with mine)

```
import SignOutButton from './components/SignOut';
```

Then you can use it anywhere you want

```
<SignOutButton />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).